# Erro StaticInjectorError ao usar Typeahead(ngx-bootstrap)

Tags: angular, angular-7

Preciso usar o typeahead em um component, vamos chamar de component1.
O typeahead também ta sendo importado em outro component(vamos chamar de component2) que é usado dentro dentro deste mesmo component1 como um modal, mas são de modules diferentes.
Quando importo o module do typeahead no component1 e mantenho no component2 ele me da esse erro

Component1.module:

```js
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FullCalendarModule,
        EventoModule,
        BloquearAgendaModalModule,
        ListaBloqueiosModalModule,
        RouterModule.forChild(agendaState),
        TypeaheadModule.forRoot()
    ],
    declarations: [AgendaComponent],
    schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Component2.module:

```js
@NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, EnderecoModule, TypeaheadModule.forRoot()],
    declarations: [EventoComponent],
    exports: [EventoComponent],
    schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
})
export class EventoModule {}
```

ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(CoraPrevineAppModule)[TypeaheadDirective -> NgControl]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[TypeaheadDirective -> NgControl]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for NgControl!
Error: StaticInjectorError(CoraPrevineAppModule)[TypeaheadDirective -> NgControl]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[TypeaheadDirective -> NgControl]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for NgControl!
    at NullInjector.get (core.js?09c9:8894)
    at resolveToken (core.js?09c9:9139)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js?09c9:9083)
    at StaticInjector.get (core.js?09c9:8980)
    at resolveToken (core.js?09c9:9139)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js?09c9:9083)
    at StaticInjector.get (core.js?09c9:8980)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js?09c9:21119)
    at NgModuleRef_.get (core.js?09c9:21808)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js?09c9:21119)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js?d135:831)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js?d135:788)
    at eval (zone.js?d135:892)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js?d135:423)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js?09c9:17279)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js?d135:422)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js?d135:195)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js?d135:601)

Answer (score 0):

Fui investigando, investigando e vi que o que causava o problema era a falta do import do FormsModule que é necessário pro typeahead ter o funcionamento do bind.